# <rejected> 'options.winnerCount is not a positive integer. (val=1)'

Tags: discord, bots

i am making a giveaway command and got this error

> 'options.winnerCount is not a positive integer. (val=1)'

Whenever I do !gstart 30s 1 nitro.I don't know have a clue how to fix it

Here is my code:

```
// Giveaway channel
let giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
// If no channel is mentionned
if(!giveawayChannel){
    return message.channel.send(':x: You have to mention a valid channel!');
}

// Giveaway duration
let giveawayDuration = args[1];
// If the duration isn't valid
if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))){
    return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid duration!');
}

// Number of winners
let giveawayNumberWinners = args[2];
// If the specified number of winners is not a number
if(isNaN(giveawayNumberWinners) || (parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners) <= 0)){
    return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid number of winners!');
}

// Giveaway prize
let giveawayPrize = args.slice(3).join(' ');
// If no prize is specified
if(!giveawayPrize){
    return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid prize!');
}

// Start the giveaway
```

bot.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
// The giveaway duration
time: ms(giveawayDuration),
// The giveaway prize
prize: giveawayPrize,
// The giveaway winner count
winnerCount: giveawayNumberWinners,
// Who hosts this giveaway
hostedBy: message.author,
// Messages
messages: {
giveaway: " **GIVEAWAY** ",
giveawayEnded: " **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ",
timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**!",
inviteToParticipate: "React with  to participate!",
winMessage: "Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{prize}**!",
embedFooter: "Giveaways",
noWinner: "Giveaway cancelled, no valid participations.",
hostedBy: "Hosted by: {user}",
winners: "winner(s)",
endedAt: "Ended at",
units: {
seconds: "seconds",
minutes: "minutes",
hours: "hours",
days: "days",
pluralS: true // Not needed, because units end with a S so it will automatically removed if the unit value is lower than 2
}
}
});

```
message.channel.send(`Giveaway started in ${giveawayChannel}!`);

}
```

}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Looks very similar to https://github.com/jagrosh/GiveawayBot, consider opening a support ticket there or double check your code.